# Change background Color with hexdecimal

Tags: android, android-activity, colors, hex

In mainActivity i take hexString then start new activity and send hexString to it
and change background color with this hex string.
i need to know if there is background color method can take argument hexString  or long .

code:

```
String colorValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("colorHex");
findViewById(R.id.layout1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorValue));//want change in the argument or if there's another method.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String))

Try with the function `public static int parseColor (String colorString)`
That take a String and return the int color!

> Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int. If the string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception. Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names: 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey', 'darkgrey', 'aqua', 'fuchsia', 'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive', 'purple', 'silver', 'teal'.

**Try something like this**

```
//find your layout
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayout);

//Get the color from an EditText
EditText newcolor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
String stringColor = newcolor.getText().toString(): //Assume that you have the #RRGGBB

//the function take only #RRGGBB with 6 values read documentation for more information
 int intColor = Color.parseColor(stringColor);

//Set the color to the LinearLayout
ll.setBackground(intColor);
```

Comment: not work it make new activity stop if i insert hex ex 0xfff.

Comment: try with #, like this `public static int parseColor("#0xfff")`
Use a try and catch because **If the string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception**

Comment: Still get down when it start new activity.

Comment: You say that the app crash, when it crash you can find the error in the logcat, copy and paste the error when the app crash.

Comment: And post more code not only the 2 row so me and other user can give more help.

Comment: Thanks for help . i was busy for answer sre for that

Answer (score 0):

assume color yellow.

```
private static int yellow = Color.parseColor("#f9ce1e");
view.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
```